# i am trying to run the following batch file with if statements but nothing happened

Tags: batch-file, cmd

this is the program

```
@echo off

if "%USERNAME%"=="ACTone"

@echo Access Denied: 
@echo Log into your ACTtwo Account to perform this task.  
@echo Press Anykey to Exit.... 

else if "%USERNAME%"=="ACTtwo"

E:\ACT\compass\bin\program.exe startB8
```

Am I using the if statements correctly because when I run it, it does nothing?

Please help, thank you

Comment: sorry I couldn't be of any help (IOW, you need to start accepting some answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

if "%USERNAME%"=="ACTone" (
    @echo Access Denied: 
    @echo Log into your ACTtwo Account to perform this task.  
    @echo Press Anykey to Exit.... 
    goto end
)
if "%USERNAME%"=="ACTtwo" (
    E:\ACT\compass\bin\program.exe startB8
    goto end
)

:end
```

Comment: Label names a referred to without the ':' – `goto end`. You might have confused it with `goto :eof` which uses a special case label pointing at the end of the file (and so you don't need to create your own 'end' label at all).

Comment: @Andriy - it appears the OP doesn't care anyway (but I'll fix it ASAP)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

`@if "%USERNAME%"=="ACTone" GOTO ONE 
:ONE
@echo IT WAS ACTone
@GOTO END
:TWO
@echo IT WAS NOT ACTone
:END`